# Is there a clearner way to show $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {h^TAh}{||h||} = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to find the gradient of $x^TAx$, and in the process, I came across the need to show that 
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {h^TAh}{||h||} = 0.$$

I can do it by expanding everything out into sums, but I was wondering if it is possible to do it more cleanly. Here's how I did it:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {h^TAh}{||h||} = \dfrac {1}{||h||}\sum_{1 \le i, j \le n} a_{ij}h_ih_j$$

$$=\sum_{1 \le i, j \le n} \dfrac {a_{ij}h_ih_j}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^nh_k^2}}$$

Now, in absolute value,

$$\le \sum_{1 \le i, j \le n} \dfrac {a_{ij}|h_i||h_j|}{\sqrt{h_i^2 + h_j^2}} \le \sum_{1 \le i, j \le n} \dfrac {a_{ij}|h_i||h_j|}{\sqrt{2|h_i||h_j|}} = \sum_{1 \le i, j \le n} \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{|h_i||h_j|}$$

and for each $i. j$, the term $\sqrt{|h_i||h_j|}$ clearly goes to $0$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: One way is as follows. You can write your expression as $\frac{h^T A h}{\|h\|^2}\|h\|$. You can then show that $\frac{h^T A h}{\|h\|^2}$ is bounded and $\|h\|\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Hmm I guess I can show it's bounded using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Is there another way?

Comment: Let $f(h) = \frac{h^T A h}{\|h\|^2}$. You can note that $f(h)=f(\alpha h)$ for any scalar $\alpha$, so it suffices to just consider $h$ on the unit ball (i.e. $\|h\| = 1$). Since $f$ is continuous on the unit ball and the unit ball is compact, the extreme value theorem implies that $f$ attains a minimum and a maximum value on the unit ball (and hence is bounded).

Comment: I mean unit sphere

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Ah I see, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the absolute value of $h^TAh$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz along with the operator norm of $A$:
$$ |h^TAh|\leq ||h||_2||Ah||_2\leq ||A||_2||h||_2^2$$

Comment: Thanks! Ah I always forget that multiplying by the transpose is just doing the dot product